# How do I use a Exclusive Or (XOR) in an Ecto query and filter by ID in a many to many relationship?

Tags: elixir, ecto

How do I use an Exclusive Or (XOR) in an Ecto query? For example I have a table of `transactions` that belong to `users`. I want to know which are "new transactions", constituting a new customer and what are older ones constituting a recurring customer. These `transactions` also belong to a `merchant`.

I would want the query, given a certain date, to tell me all the transactions for users that have new transactions since that date but never had a transaction before that.  I should be able to do the reverse by being able to see what users had transactions before a certain date and not after that. Users that have transactions before and after the date should be excluded from both.

It is easy to get all the `transactions` for the `merchant`

```
def merchant_transactions(merchant_id) do
  from t in Transactions,
  where: t.merchant_id == ^merchant_id
end
```

but now I need to filter the transactions by User, as if I'm grouping them by `user_id`, then filtering by

```
#this feels wrong and is wrong, how I compare the records to each other?
def get_transactions_from_new_users(query) do
  from t in query,
  where: t.user_id == t.user_id,
  where: ...

end
```

It makes more sense in a loop:

```
#Psuedo (Non-SQL) code

users = get all the users for a merchant <- return all users through transactions
for each user, get transactions
  if the user has transactions before and after the date, remove them from the list
  if the user has transactions before the date, remove them from the list
```

I feel like a join some how would work, and then filter it on the `user_id` and `inserted_at` field, although I run into the same problem of comparing transactions to each other in the filter.

The last option I have been considering is getting a list of transactions before the date and a list of transactions after the date. Then filter by user and if the user is in both lists, remove both transactions.

Update 1/9/2018:

I was able to cook up some SQL to provide the functionality with the `WITH` SQL statement:

```
WITH new_transactions AS (
       select * from transactions
       where merchant_id = 1 and inserted_at > date '2017-11-01'
     ), older_transactions AS (
        select * from transactions
        where merchant_id = 1 and inserted_at < date '2017-11-01'
     )
SELECT * from new_transactions
WHERE user_id NOT IN (select user_id from older_transactions);
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to run this kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know if given transaction is given user first one. If so you can use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10.1/interactive/tutorial-window.html) if your DB engine supports them.

So your query will look like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS count
    FROM transactions
) AS q WHERE count = 1;
```

Ecto doesn't have native support for window functions nor support for select from subquery, so you need to use hack it away:

```
counts =
  from t in Transaction,
  where: t.merchant_id == ^merchant_id
  select: %{
    id: t.id,
    count: fragment("COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ?)", t.user_id),
  }

from t in Transaction,
inner_join: counts in subquery(counts), on: counts.id == t.id,
where: counts.count == 1
```

It can be a little simpler with `window-functions` branch of [Ecto.OLAP](https://github.com/hauleth/ecto_olap/blob/622042722394e0e26bf259a12fa56e0abb9fd0a4/lib/window.ex) (shameless plug, still WIP).

```
counts =
  from t in Transaction,
  where: t.merchant_id == ^merchant_id
  select: %{
    id: t.id,
    count: window(count(t.id), over: [partition_by: t.user_id]),
  }

from t in Transaction,
inner_join: counts in subquery(counts), on: counts.id == t.id,
where: counts.count == 1
```

Comment: Thanks @hauleth, I think I got it mostly with the update I put in. I think I need to use the `subquery` in place of the sql `WITH` statement for ecto to pick it up.